# Minimizing $x^{\frac32}$ over the non-negative reals as a SOCP

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

I am trying to solve the following optimization problem ([Problem 9.2](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z7MQvs9CsoYC&lpg=PA170&ots=ge9f1GWluU&dq=%22Express%20the%20second%20problem%20as%20an%20SOCP%20using%22&pg=PA170#v=onepage&q=%22Express%20the%20second%20problem%20as%20an%20SOCP%20using%22&f=false)) which can be setup as an SOCP.

$$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x}{\text{minimize}}
& & x^{\frac{3}{2}} \\
& \text{subject to}
& & x \geq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$$

I can restate it as follows
$$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x,\, t}{\text{minimize}}
& & t \\
& \text{subject to}
& x^{\frac{3}{2}} \leq t \\
& & x \geq 0,\, t \geq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$$

I can further simplify it by multiplying the inequality constraint by $\sqrt{x}$, which is positive, and thus the inequality remains unchanged. Then we substitute, $u = \sqrt{x}$ on the right-hand side to get the following problem. Here the variables t and u must also be non-negative
$$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x, \, t, \, u}{\text{minimize}}
& & t \\
& \text{subject to}
& x^2 \leq tu \\
& & u^2 = x \\
& & x \geq 0,\, t \geq 0,\,  \geq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$$

Now I can split the quadratic equality constraint into 2 inequality constraints
$$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x, \, t, \, u}{\text{minimize}}
& & t \\
& \text{subject to}
& x^2 \leq tu \\
& & u^2 \leq x \\
& & u^2 \geq x \\
& & x \geq 0,\, t \geq 0,\, u \geq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$$

I can see how the first two constraints can be setup as 2 separate rotated cone constraints to give a valid SOCP. However, I don't understand how the author got rid of the third inequality constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the $u^2 \geq x$ condition, as it never would be optimal to violate this constraint (to make $t$ small, you want to make $u^2$ large, hence the second constraint will be active)

Comment: There is no constraint such as $u^2 \geq t$ in the problem

Comment: The larger I make $u$, the smaller I can make $t$ to keep the first constraint active. The second constraint restricts that movement of $u$ to the domain $\left[0,\sqrt{x}\right]$. The third constraint restricts that movement to the domain $\left[\sqrt{x},\infty\right)$. Dropping the second instead of third constraint gives me a greater reduction in t. So, why should I keep the second and drop the third constraint ?

Comment: I meant $u^2 \geq x$. You keep the second constraint to ensure $u^2 = x$ at optimality.

Answer (score 0):

The way is to introduce an additional variable and use two second-order cones. From $x^{3/2}\leq t$ we get

$$
x^{3/2} = \frac{x^{2}}{x^{1/2}},
$$

and therefore

$$
t\geq x^{3/2} \Rightarrow t x^{1/2}\geq x^2.
$$

Introducing $s\geq 0$ we obtain

$$
2st\geq x^2,\\
2s\leq x^{1/2},
$$

that leads to

$$
2st\geq x^2,\\
1/4 x \geq s^{2}.
$$

The overall problem takes the form:

$$
\min t\\
(t,s,x)\in \mathit{Q_r^3},\\
(1/8,x,s)\in \mathit{Q_r^3},\\ 
s,t,x\geq 0.
$$

See http://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html#simple-polynomial-sets for more details.

Comment: Thanks I saw that on Mosek's website. My problem has always been with the introduction of $2s \leq x^{1/2}$ constraint. I would always start with saying $2s = x^{1/2}$ and then splitting into 2 constraints, $2s \leq x^{1/2}$ and $2s \geq x^{1/2}$. Sadly, I always found that docs trivially removed the constriant, $2s \geq x^{1/2}$ without any justification, including the one cited above from Mosek.

Comment: @Andrea I am working on a quadratic programming problem where after getting rid of the $x$ in the Lagrangian, I can't figure out how to find the dual problem. Can you please help? There is a 100 point bounty on the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2571031/need-help-setting-up-and-solving-dual-problem