# Need help setting up and solving dual problem

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems, quadratic-programming

I need to solve the quadratic programming problem $$ \text{minimize}\,\, \sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_{j})^{2} \\ \text{subject to}\,\,\, \sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}=1,\\ 0 \leq x_{j}\leq u_{j}, \, \, j=1,\cdots , n $$

I know that the first thing I need to do is form the Lagrangian.

Now, for a problem in standard form (note that below, $\overline{x}$, $\overline{\lambda}$, $\overline{\mu}$ denote vectors): $$ \text{minimize} \, \, f_{0}(\overline{x}) \\ \text{subject to} \,\,\, f_{i}(\overline{x}), \,\,\, i=1,\cdots, m \\ h_{i}(\overline{x}), \,\,\, i = 1,\cdots, p $$ the Lagrangian looks like this:  $\displaystyle L(\overline{x},\overline{\lambda}, \overline{\mu}) = f_{0}(x) + \sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_{i}f_{i}(\overline{x}) + \sum_{i=1}^{p}\mu_{i}h_{i}(\overline{x})$

In this case, I am being thrown off by the fact that my sole $h_{i}(\overline{x})$ happens to be a sum that adds up to $1$, and if I want my $f_{i}(\overline{x})$'s to be $\leq 0$, I'm going to need to rewrite the last line of constraints as $x_{j} - u_{j} \leq 0$, $j = 1,\cdots , n$ and $-x_{j} \leq 0$, $j = 1, \cdots, n$.

Then, would my Lagrangian be $\displaystyle L(\overline{x},\overline{\lambda}, \overline{\mu}) = \sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_{j})^{2} + \sum_{j=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}(x_{j}-u_{j}) + \sum_{j=1}^{n}\nu_{i} (-x_{i}) + \mu\left[\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j} \right)-1\right]$ ?

**And then, how would I go about completing the problem?** I've never done a problem with this many Lagrange variables in it before, nor with this many constraints, and so I'm finding it a little overwhelming...

Thank you ahead of time for your time and patience!

Comment: You missed $n$ inequality constraints: $-x_j \le 0$.

Comment: @MathLover where? I thought that would have been included in the $x_{j}-u_{j}$'s...

Comment: What does $0 \le x_j \le u_j$ mean?

Comment: It means that $\forall j$, $u_{j} \geq x_{j}$, and since $x_{j} \geq 0$ $\forall j$, if I subtract from each $x_{j}$ its corresponding $u_{j}$, I will get constraints that are $\leq 0$, like I need in order for this problem to be of standard form. I understand what you mean by having $- x_{j} \leq 0$, but doing this does not take into account that each $x_{j}$ is bounded above by something. Is that unimportant?

Comment: Does $x_j \le 2$ imply that $x_j \ge 0$???? The inequality $0 \le x_j \le u_j$ is actually two inequalities: $0 \le x_j$ and $x_j \le u_j$.

Comment: @MathLover now I understand what you were trying to say! So, I need to adjust my Lagrangian. So, the $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\lambda_{i} (x_{j}-u_{j})$ takes care of the $x_{j} \leq u_{j}$ inequalities. Now, for the $0 \leq x_{j}$, I need to rewrite them as $-x_{j} \leq 0$...so then, do I add a term to my Lagrangian, say $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\nu_{i} (-x_{i})$? Is that how I would take care of those inequalities in my Lagrangian?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to say that you missed $n$ inequalities.

Comment: @MathLover okay, so I'll edit my question above. Wasn't sure if I needed an entire other multiplier letter for that. Now, I still am not sure how to proceed once I even have that. So, once I edit my question, if you still want to help me with going forward from there, I'd much appreciate it ;) Of course, I already appreciate what you've done to help me thus far!

Comment: Presumably $\sum_k u_k \ge 1$.

Comment: @MathLover: the inequalities do not go into the Lagrangian. The boundaries of the inequalities form new constraints for a lower dimensional Lagrangian.

Comment: @robjohn I think knowing this from the beginning would have saved me a lot of headache! I can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Basic Variational Approach**

Since
$$
\sum_{j=1}^nx_j=1\tag1
$$
any variation of the $x_j$'s must satisfy
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n\delta x_j=0\tag2
$$
At an interior critical point of
$$
\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^2\tag3
$$
we will have
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n2x_j\delta x_j=0\tag4
$$
At an interior critical point, any change that maintains $(1)$ should not change $(3)$. That is, for any $\delta x_j$ that satisfies $(2)$, $\delta x_j$ should satisfy $(4)$.

Note that $(2)$ says that $(\delta x_1,\delta x_2, \delta x_3,\dots,\delta x_n)$ is perpendicular to $(1,1,1,\dots,1)$, and that is the only restriction on $\delta x_j$, unless $x_j=0$ or $x_j=u_j$ (the edge cases). Furthermore, $(4)$ is satisfied when $(\delta x_1,\delta x_2, \delta x_3,\dots,\delta x_n)$ is perpendicular to $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n)$. This means that any $(\delta x_j)$ that is perpendicular to $(1,1,1,\dots,1)$ is perpendicular to $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n)$. That is, $(1,1,1,\dots,1)$ is parallel to $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n)$.

Thus, the only interior critical points happen when
$$
x_1=x_2=x_3=\dots=x_n=\lambda\tag5
$$
In light of $(1)$, this means that
$$
(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n)=\tfrac1n\left(1,1,1,\dots,1\right)\tag6
$$
We also need to check the edge cases where some $x_j=0$ or some $x_j=u_j$. In those cases, we still have the analog of $(5)$ for the interior $x_j$; that is, those for which $0\lt x_j\lt u_j$.

---

**Lagrangian Approach**

The Lagrangian would be
$$
\mathcal{L}(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n,\lambda)=\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^2-\lambda\left(\sum_{j=1}^nx_j-1\right)\tag7
$$
Taking the gradient this locates the interior critical points
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=\nabla\mathcal{L}(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n,\lambda)\\
&=\left(2x_1-\lambda,2x_2-\lambda,2x_3-\lambda,\dots,2x_n-\lambda,\sum_{j=1}^nx_j-1\right)\tag8
\end{align}
$$
which we can solve to get $(6)$.

There are $2n$ $n-1$ dimensional edges, where $x_j=0$ and $x_j=u_j$, and a number of corners, etc. that need to be considered separately. They are not handled in the $n$-dimensional Lagrangian, though we can consider separate $n-1$ dimensional Lagrangians.

Comment: I think your answer is useful, but it would be more useful contextualized within the  framework of the work I did on my own in my original post.  Nobody has done that so far, which is really what I am looking for in order to accept and award. More importantly though it's what I need in order to finally understand!

Comment: I have to admit to you that I still don't have this problem completely figured out. I was able to form the $n-1$ dimensional Lagrangian and find the general form for critical points when some of the $x_{j}=0$ (they would not be optimal though, because the more indices where the $x$'s $=0$, the larger the value of the objective function. How do I approach it in the case where some of the $x_{j} = u_{j}$? As in, how do I form the $n-1$ dimensional Lagrangian for it and find the critical points?

Comment: @ALannister: It's just the same as the case when some of the $x_j=0$. For example, if $x_1=u_1$ and $x_2=u_2$, then the problem becomes to minimize $$\sum_{j=3}^nx_j^2$$ under the constraint $$\sum_{j=3}^nx_j=1-u_1-u_2$$

Comment: I'm going to have to work through that case. You know, originally, when I was given this problem to work on, I was told as a hint: "use duality", but I honestly cannot see how duality can help us. Also, the way we're doing it here, are the cases where some of the $x_{j}=u_{j}$ also not going to be optimal?

Comment: @ALannister: the Lagrangian method only finds internal extrema. The boundary extrema have to be checked separately. It may be that the extremum we want is an internal one and none of the edge cases are what we want. However, we still need to check them or account for them some other way.

Comment: in trying to solve for the critical points in this case, things are getting very complicated: If I form $L(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots, x_{n}, \lambda)= \sum_{j=l+1}^{n}x_{j}^{2}-\lambda \sum_{j=l+1}^{n}x_{j} + \lambda - \lambda \sum_{j=1}^{l}u_{j}$, then set the gradient equal to zero: $0 = \nabla L(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots, x_{n}, \lambda) = (0, 0, 0, \cdots, 0, 2x_{l+1}-\lambda, 2x_{l+2}-\lambda, \cdots, 2x_{n}-\lambda, 1-\sum_{j=1}^{l}u_{j}-\sum_{j=l+1}^{n}x_{j})$, each $x_{i} = \frac{\lambda}{2}$, where $i \geq l+1$...

Comment: so $\lambda = \frac{2}{n-l}-\frac{2}{n-l}\sum_{j=1}^{l}u_{j}$. Therefore, $x_{l+1}=x_{l+2} = \cdots = x_{n} = \frac{1}{n-l}-\frac{1}{n-l}\sum_{j=1}^{l}u_{j}$, which means our critical points are of the form $\displaystyle \left( u_{1}, u_{2}, \cdots , u_{l} , \frac{1}{n-l}-\frac{1}{n-l}\sum_{j=1}^{l}u_{j}, \cdots , \frac{1}{n-l}\sum_{j=1}^{l}u_{j} \right)$. Now, how the heck am I supposed to show that the sum of the squares of each of those components is larger than the sum of squares of the components we got for the case when none of the $x_{i} = 0$ or $x_{i} = u_{i}$?

Comment: I tried to simplify $\sum_{j=1}^{l}u_{j}^{2} + \sum_{j=1}^{l}\left(\frac{1}{n-l}-\frac{1}{n-l}\sum_{j=1}^{l}u_{j} \right)^{2}$, but things got really ugly really fast. Is there some kind of trick I'm missing here?

Comment: @ALannister: I'm sorry this gets complicated, but as you see in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2570890), the maximum and minimum occur on the edges and corners. Depending on the $u_j$, the minimum here may be on an edge or corner.

Comment: since for any $i$, $u_{i}\geq x_{i}$, we can't say that an objective function with $u_{i}'s $ plugged into it must come out to be larger than one  without them?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into space limitations, so here is what I wanted as a comment:

Hi @ALannister:

1] if the $u_i$'s are large, then the solution is $\tfrac{1}{n}\mathbf{e}_n$, where $\mathbf{e}_n$ is the vector of all $1$'s in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

2] view your problem as a projection problem: you want to project the origin onto the intersection of the box with the hyperplane with normal vector $\mathbf{e}_n$ and offset value $1$.

3] For notational convenience, assume $u_1\leq u_2\leq\cdots\leq u_n$.

4] As you blow up the ball (intersected with the nonnegative orthant), it will either hit first the hyperplane or the boundary of the box you are given.

5] If it hits the hyperplane first, then you are done (the problem is really unconstrained).

6] If you hit the box boundary first, you will hit it at $x_1=u_1$. This value is now fixed.

7] The remaining variables $x_2,\ldots x_n$ are now in a box of one less dimension, and the hyperplane has now normal vector $\mathbf{e}_{n-1}$, the all-ones in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, and the offset is $1-u_1$.

8] Repeat this argument until you are done. This leads to your solution.

I suspect this is known. Is this a homework in a book? If so, please let us know from where this problem comes from, it is neat.

Comment: it's homework, but it's not from a book. These comments are interesting, and essentially are spoilers as to what the final answer is, but it's not really what I was looking for. I was looking for something to help me bridge the gap between $L(\frac{1}{2}\left( \nu - \lambda - \mu e \right), \lambda, \nu, \mu)$ and the final answer. For one thing, once I have this expression for $L$, I don't know what the dual is. I need to express that explicitly.

Comment: can you give me any pointers in that regard?

Comment: I suggest you look at the proof of how one projects onto the $r$-simplex, which corresponds to the case when $u_i\equiv +\infty$ but the hyperplane offset if $=r$. In Lange's book *MM Optimization Algorithms*, Example 5.3.2, you find this done with Lagrange multipliers, you find the solution *and the values of the multipliers*. You can regard this as a "subproblem" of what I outlined and adjust accordingly. I would still think this is known and published somewhere, please report back once you get the solution. Thanks and good luck!

Comment: PS: Lange points to a paper by Duchi, Shalev-Shwartz, Singer and Chandra from 2002 entitled "Efficient projection onto the $\ell_1$-ball for learning in high dimensions."

Comment: that's very interesting, but I don't it's going to help me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please give it a shot, it is exactly what you need. Also, I would replace the objective function by $\tfrac{1}{2}\|x\|^2$ to get rid of the annoying factor of $2$ in your KKT conditions (same solution at the end of course).

Comment: it might be exactly what I need, but the problem is that I can't visualize it. My course isn't that advanced, and a lot of the stuff you said, I've never even heard of. I can't even visualize what any of that stuff would look like translated into mathematical writing.

Comment: for one thing I don't know what an $r$-simplex is. And I don't know what you mean by a "projection problem".

Comment: I've even seen what another student in class did - although his solution is not correrct, because he doesn't have enough multipliers for all the conditions in his Lagrangian. The problem is is that my Lagrangian is soooo complicated! I imagine *maybe* that some of those hints might help me make the Lagrangian simpler, but I don't know enough to see how.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70714/discussion-between-alannister-and-max-zorn).

Comment: Your equality constraints has $=1$, replace this by $=r$. If you keep the $x_i$ positive, then you get the $r$-simplex. As for the projection problem: Draw this in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Your objective function $\|x\|^2$ means you are looking for a vector of minimal norm, i.e, the projection of the origin onto the intersection of the hyperplane and the box with the lower/upper bounds given.

Answer (score 1):

The primal problem is $\inf_x \sup_{\mu, \lambda \ge 0, \nu \ge 0 } L(x,\lambda, \nu, \mu)$, the dual is $ \sup_{\mu, \lambda \ge 0, \nu \ge 0 }\inf_x  L(x,\lambda, \nu, \mu)$.

Since ${\partial L(x,\lambda, \nu, \mu) \over \partial x} = 2x + \lambda - \nu + \mu e$, where $e=(1,1,...)^T$, we can compute an explicit expression for the
minimising $x$ and so compute a formula for $\inf_x  L(x,\lambda, \nu, \mu)$.

Comment: I don't understand how that can be the partial w.r.t. $x$. What about all the summations? Where did they go? Unless this is the partial w.r.t. $x_{i}$ for some $i$? Then, the derivatives of the other ones would equal $0$?

Comment: The summations didn't go away. If you prefer, compute ${\partial L(x,\lambda, \nu, \mu) \over \partial x_k}$ instead. Since $x \mapsto L(x,\lambda, \nu, \mu) $ is a (positive definite) quadratic, the function has a unique minimiser at the value of $x$ for which the derivative is zero.

Comment: okay, so $\frac{\partial L(x ,\lambda, \nu,\mu)}{\partial x_{k}} = 2x_{k}+\lambda_{k}-\nu_{k}+\mu$, and then $\nabla_{x}L(x,\lambda, \nu, \mu) = 2x + \lambda - \nu + \mu e$, where $e = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Then, $2x + \lambda - \nu + \mu e = 0$ implies that $x = \frac{1}{2}\nu - \frac{1}{2}\lambda - \frac{1}{2}\mu e$. So, how do I substitute this into my Lagrangian so that I can obtain the dual problem? Also, since $0 \leq x_{j}$ $\forall j$, does $x = \frac{1}{2}\nu - \frac{1}{2}\lambda - \frac{1}{2}\mu e$ imply that $\lambda + \mu e \leq\nu$?

Comment: okay, if I can't finish figuring this out by myself today, tomorrow I'll post a bounty.

Comment: Well, just compute $L({1 \over 2}(\nu-\lambda - \mu e),\lambda, \nu, \mu)$. The dual problem is then $\sup_{\mu, \lambda \ge 0, \nu \ge 0 } L({1 \over 2}(\nu-\lambda - \mu e),\lambda, \nu, \mu)$. And no, $x$ just solves the inner problem for  given $(\lambda, \nu, \mu)$, the constraints on the dual variables are as in the $\sup$. There is no reason, a priori, to suppose that $x \ge 0$ for any given $(\lambda, \nu, \mu)$.

Comment: even though in the primal problem, we're told that $x\geq 0$?

Comment: In the primal, the constraints are 'enforced' by the multipliers, that is, the quantity $\sup_{\mu, \lambda \ge 0, \nu \ge 0 } L(x,\lambda, \nu, \mu)$ is infinite when the constraints are not satisfied. Think of it this way, we are trying to minimise over $x$ subject to the constraints being satisfied. In the dual, we are sort of doing the opposite, we are trying to maximise (over the dual variables) subject to the constraint that we are at the minimum value over $x$. So, yes, the primal has the constraint $x \ge 0$, and that is reflected in the $\nu$ dual variable....

Comment: But $x \ge 0$ does not appear as a constraint in the dual. In fact, $x$ has disappeared in the dual. In general, there is no guarantee that the dual value will equal the primal value (we are guaranteed $\le$). In some cases, such as a convex quadratic cost with affine constraints (such as the case here) we know that the duality gap is zero as long as either problem is feasible.

Comment: if you write out $L(\frac{1}{2}(\nu - \lambda - \mu e), \lambda, \nu, \mu) = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left[\frac{1}{4}\left( \nu_{j}^{2}+\lambda_{j}^{2}+\mu^{2}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\left (\nu_{j}\lambda_{j} + \mu \nu_{j} + \mu \lambda_{j}\right) \right] + \sum_{j=1}^{n} \lambda_{j} \left( \frac{1}{2}\left(\nu_{j}-\lambda_{j}-\mu\right)-u_{j}\right)-\sum_{j=1}^{n}\nu_{j}\left( \frac{1}{2}\left(\nu_{j}-\lambda_{j}-\mu\right)\right) + \mu\left[\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2}\left( \nu_{j}-\lambda_{j}-\mu \right) \right) - 1 \right]$

Comment: in other words, it's so nightmarish that it took me three times to check through it and find all the parentheses I forgot to type just so that it would render properly! Now, I need to find $\sup$ of that in order to form the dual problem, and hopefully some constraints will pop out of that. My question is, how do I do that? I can't use the primal constraints to help me figure out what the $\sup$ should be, so how do I do it? If you want, I can put up a bounty. If you add these details to your answer, I will award it to you.

Comment: Just remember, I have to be able to actually solve this dual once we've found it.So, I hope it's not too hairy :(

Comment: The dual problem is to find the $\sup $ of the concave quadratic subject to linear constraints.

Comment: I am not in it for the points/bounty. If I help with your understanding that it my reward.

Comment: I know, and I wish more people were like you in that regard :) About the problem, though, can you edit your answer to include the details I'm asking about here? Just taking the sup of the lagrangian and how the details of that go? That would help with my understanding a lot.

Comment: I still have no idea how to calculate the $\sup$ of that $L(\frac{1}{2}(\nu-\lambda - \mu e), \lambda, \nu, \mu)$, and how to get rid of the $u$'s that appear in it. Could you please continue to help me with this? It's been days and nothing has worked.

Comment: Hi @ALannister: Do you know a priori that your problem has a solution (it won't if the $u_i$'s are collectively too small). Do you care about a closed-form solution or just algorithms to do it numerically?

Comment: @max_zorn yes, it's supoosed to have a solution. I'm not interested in doing it numerically. I'm supposed to find a closed-form solution by finding the sup of the Lagrangian. I think I'm close to a solution, but I can't figure out how to finish setting up the dual problem and solve for the multipliers.

Comment: Hi @ALannister: First, if the $u_i$'s are large, then the solution is $\tfrac{1}{n}\mathbf{e}_n$, where $\mathbf{e}_n$ is the vector of all $1$'s in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Second, view your problem as a projection problem: you want to project the origin onto the intersection of the box with the hyperplane with normal vector $\mathbf{e}_n$ and offset value $1$.

Comment: You are finding the nearest point to the origin in the set formed by the constraints. You do need to specify the $u_k$.

Comment: @copper.hat but I don't know what the dual and its constraints are, so... You told me it's a convex quadratic, but how do I get a convex quadratic out of that monstrosity I wrote out above? That's all I want to know.

Comment: The problem as stated may have a duality gap. If $\sum_k u_k < 1$ the feasible set is empty. The dual problem is to find the $\sup $ of $L({1 \over 2}(\nu-\lambda - \mu e),\lambda, \nu, \mu)$ subject to the constraints $\lambda \ge0, \nu \ge 0$ and $\mu$ is unconstrained. This **is** the dual problem.